# Goland showing Unresolved type (Instance, in GCE library specifically), but core/tests run fine ("invalidate and restart" solution not working here)

Tags: google-compute-engine, goland

I'm using the GCE library in Go, along with go modules.

I'm finding that, while it happily compiles and runs unit tests, it's not resolving those types (e.g. compute.Instance) in the Goland IDE. I'm using 2020.2.

I first added this dependency by hand-coding (adding `"google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"` to my imports, and letting the module handler load whatever it needs). It added `google.golang.org/api v0.50.0` to my `go.mod` file.

I've tried the old "Invalidate and Restart" approach, and it didn't do anything. I have another project where a different version of that module happens to be loaded, and it works fine on that one.

I've even tried a more nuclear version (Invalidate (no restart), close project, close IDE, delete the `.idea` directory, and delete the contents of `~/.cache/JetBrains`). Still no dice.

FWIW my go module's version is `go 1.15`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can navigate to the package sources by pressing `Command/CTRL+Click` on the import statement (or via External Libraries menu in Project View) and find `compute-gen.go` file and size limit warning. The IDE behaves as expected.

[image]

As a workaround, you can invoke `Help | Edit Custom Properties...` and add the following line `idea.max.intellisense.filesize=8500000` (depends on the original file size), restart GoLand. Please, keep in mind that the IDE can be slow when dealing with large files even if they are not open in the editor.

You can read more about the `idea.properties` file [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869).

Comment: Nice, that seems to have worked, thanks! It was weird because this worked on another project just a couple days ago, and the file size can't have changed all that much. I even recall loading the module through one of the types (ctrl-alt-B), and it loaded, and still displayed the "it's a large file" warning.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a project-level override for these settings, or even a "per-file exception"? I don't want to default the number to be too high, if it's going to load a bunch of large dependencies I don't care about behind the scenes as a result.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the IDE-wide setting and you cannot edit it per project. Feel free to follow [IDEA-262830](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-262830).